# find only certain strings (domain) extract another file

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have bunch of lines in `findmydomain.txt` and would like to extract only those domain names which don't have a path after the domain and save them in a new file.

I couldn't figured out how to do this because some domain names finish in `.gov`, some in `.vn`, some don't have `www` etc..

I am expecting to extract only domain names without a filepath to a new file. For example:

```
http://www.drexel.edu/
http://trianglewordpress.com/
http://www.nasa.gov/
http://www.mexico.com.mx/
```

findmydomain.txt

```
http://www.safmls.org/2009/2009%20Presentations/Hemostasis%20-%20Stop%20Doing%20Bleeding%20Times.doc
http://debsabo.com/Luke_2.doc
http://lessons.ctaponline.org/~ferson/worksheets/Factoring%20Trinomials.doc
http://shalegasconsortium.com/down12547
http://www.auburnschools.org/drake/jwilliams/New%20Stuff/Review%20Questions%20for%20Evolution%20and%20Changing%20Populations.docx
http://static.schoolrack.com/files/28065/668560/APHUG_Chapter_4.ppsx
http://medicine.missouri.edu/docs/financial/Student%20Loan%20Forgiveness.docx
http://personales.upv.es/jpgarcia/LinkedDocuments/P&LLayout.doc
http://www.drexel.edu/
http://www.cardiotimes.com/documents/powerpoints/SLI022.doc
http://www.dot.state.oh.us/projects/pdp/Related%20Documents/Project%20Development%20Process%20Scoping%20Training.docx
http://www.fhs.d211.org/departments/english/gdawson/short%20story%20terms.docx
http://www.gregorydoublewing.com/Lonesome_Polecat.doc
http://www.cs.iit.edu/~cs549/cs549s07/CryptographyNetSecurity-2008.doc
http://cmsachesapeake.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Current-Concepts-in-Concussion-Care.docx
http://liffeysoundfm.ie/cheap-alli-tablets-uk.docx
http://mepag.nasa.gov/meeting/2008-02/MEPAG_Feb_2008_McCuistion21.doc
http://trianglewordpress.com/
http://www.kvsangathanectlt.com/topic_sys/767639292The%20Mirror.doc
http://people.eku.edu/sumithrans/Zoo/labs/Pseudocoelomates.doc
http://www.examvault.net/uploads/3/0/1/5/30157763/f211_cell_membrane.docx
http://www.dgelman.com/powerpoints/statistics/spitz/5.2%20The%20standard%20Normal%20Distribution.doc
http://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/jwathen/Chapter%20S26.4%20through%206.doc
http://www.npti.in/Download/Renewable/POWERGEN%20PRSTN_Renewable%20April2012/Centralized%20Remote%20Monitoring%20of%20Renewable%20Power%20Plants.ppsx
https://mail.alquds.edu/~f2095/Communication%20Systems/Introduction.doc
http://cdffa.org/Documents/CPR_AED_presentation.doc
http://www.nasa.gov/
http://faculty.caldwell.edu/kreeve/Chap%2021%20-%20Critical%20Thinking%202013.docx
http://www.agriseta.co.za/downloads/Agriseta_Sep_18_2014_Ngomane.docx
http://nttc.columbiabasin.edu/automotive/CBC_doc/AC/AC%20Case%20and%20Duct%20System.docx
http://www.aoa.gov/AoA_Programs/HPW/Alz_Grants/docs/Caregiving-Feb14-2013-SKeller_Caregiving_for_people_with_dementia_and_ID-Down-syndrome.doc
http://www.hetdijkmagazijn.nl/fosamax-dosage-for-dogs.docx
https://partner.microsoft.com/download/portugal/40096973
http://www.ohio.edu/people/shriver/308/TCOM%20308-6-Radio%20Frequencies.doc
http://www.advocatehealth.com/documents/clinicalevents/Cervical_Insufficiency-McCulloch.doc
http://www.unesco.org/bsp/eng/UNESCOMDG.doc
http://iris.nyit.edu/~kkhoo/Summer1_2008/715-OOAD/Larman_doc/LarmanChap12.doc
http://www.shs.d211.org/socialstudies/faculty/AJP/The%20significance%20of%20ancient%20Persia%203.doc
http://trojan.troy.edu/studentsupportservices/assets/documents/presentations/english_reading/BasicBusinessWriting.doc
http://www.drradloff.com/documents/the-alchemist-introduction.doc
http://tc3.hccs.edu/itse1402/Shows/COBOL%20Unit1%20slides.doc
http://www.outreach.mcb.harvard.edu/teachers/Summer04/Barbara%20Gould/Handwashing_Activity_1.doc
http://images.pcmac.org/Uploads/WestCarroll/WestCarroll/Divisions/Presentations/2013-14%20TCAP%20Writing%20Assessment.docx
http://www.ltisdschools.org/cms/lib09/TX21000349/Centricity/Domain/552/REPRODUCTIONandGENETICS.docx
http://www.green-eu.net/system/files/documents/Green%20Training%20Audit_Romano.docx
http://www.panbc.net/files/multimodal_analgesia.docx
http://www.unco.edu/nhs/physics/faculty/adams/Phys%20221/MRI_2013.doc
http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/context/roadschool/article/1075/type/native/viewcontent
http://bealertbealive.com/Road%20Safety%20Powerpoint.docx
https://www.sde.idaho.gov/site/superintendentMeeting/2014pres/annual/Tiered%20Licensure.docx
http://students.salisbury.edu/~ab67028/EDUC318/Technology%20Standards.doc
http://www.ic.ucsc.edu/~rlipsch/EE80S/Global%20Sustainability.doc
http://www.earth4567.com/talks/evolution/evolution.doc
http://www.dra.ca.gov/uploadedFiles/Content/Energy/Procurement/PGE_Oakley/EMC%20presentation%20may%2016%202012.doc
http://studentaffairs.com/vcs/2011entries/NorthCarolinaStateUniversity-lupica-ewsuk.docx
https://intermec.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/161443/0/filename/Intermec+Firmware+Management+Tool1.docx
http://www.karunadu.gov.in/spb/SeminarsFinancing/Sridharan.doc
https://www.homeworkmarket.com/sites/default/files/qx/15/01/20/01/pain_theories_and_treatment_presentation.docx
http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/eltamaly/Documents/student%20forum/Future%20Student%20Projects/PV1/pv.ppsx
http://www.cuhmmc2015.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/National-Domestic-Preparedness-Consortium-Recovered1.doc
http://www.uky.edu/~clthyn2/PS671/Concepts_and_Theory_in_Political_Science.docx
http://glearning.tju.edu.cn/pluginfile.php/60967/mod_data/content/51160/%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87%E6%8A%A5%E5%91%8A.docx
http://www.biblestudies-online.com/Sermons/PowerPoint_Sermons/Genesis/1%20Genesis%20Foundation%201st%20Sermon.ppsx
http://graphics.ucsd.edu/courses/cse191_s03/CSE191_04.doc
http://www.me.uprm.edu/sundaram/inme%204007/INME4007-3.doc
http://www.csb.uncw.edu/people/rosenl/classes/OPS372/Topic%204%20New%20Service%20Developmnt.doc
https://testing.byui.edu/info/powerpoint/Test%20Center%20Finals.pps
http://bizconst.org/jam.php?how-to-make-cialis-effective.docx
http://www.co.nueces.tx.us/risk/training/Safe%20Driving%20Practices.pps
http://apalachee.elearning4u.net/pluginfile.php/9320/mod_resource/content/0/English%20Constitutionalism.doc
http://nygma.hu/dl/Golive_timer_1.doc
http://www.ccis313.blog.com/files/2013/02/is313-Lecture4.docx
http://impact.asu.edu/Presentations/Mobicom-Talk.doc
http://www.radiographyonline.com/article/S1078-8174(09)00066-2/doc
http://www.fao.org/fileadmin/user_upload/animalwelfare/Animal%20Welfare%20-%20Global%20Summary%20of%20Standard%20+%20Programs.doc
http://ebooks-kings.com/doc/chapter-16-the-reproductive-system-answer-key
http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/lee/cs157b/29SpCS157BL13BCNF&Lossless.doc
http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/Al-Fakey/Medical%20Student%20Lictures/Anatomy%20and%20Physiology.doc
http://connect.issaquah.wednet.edu/high/liberty/staff/ms_andersons_site/chemistry/m/chemistry_files_2015-16/235721/download.aspx
http://www.radford.edu/~cshing/340/lectures/Mannino/doc/CHAP006%20-%20Problems.doc
https://www.uco.edu/academic-affairs/cqi/files/docs/facilitator_tools/06.06.21-dashboardshandout.doc
http://www.llakes.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Laura-James.docx
http://www.agrisk.umn.edu/conference/uploads/WMcGee1678_01.docx
http://kith.episerverhotell.net/upload/2585/sandefjord2005_ote.doc
http://faweb.loyolablakefield.org/ClassDocuments/4977/TYPES%20OF%20STATES.docx
http://committees.comsoc.org/tccc/ccw/2010/slides/20-Cynthia.docx
http://www2.sunysuffolk.edu/mancuse/nursing/NUR%20246%20Spring%2011/Workshop%20presentations%202011%20L&M%20newest.doc
http://www.anslab.iastate.edu/Class/AnS320/ToBeRemoved/Fall%202012/Lecture/AnS%20320%20-%202012%20Fall%20-%20Swine%20Lecture%20%231.docx
http://psych.stanford.edu/~jlm/Presentations/SymSys100_04-07-09-AreHumansRational.doc
http://www.ksums.net/files/1st/Archive/01.Foundation%20Block/Male/Pathology/Neoplasia%20Lecture%201%20&%202.docx
http://www.curriculumsupport.education.nsw.gov.au/secondary/hsie/assets/aust_curriculum/aust_curriculum.docx
http://www.labour.gov.za/DOL/downloads/documents/useful-documents/occupational-health-and-safety/Construction%20Workers%20(SASOM-DoL%20Feb2011).doc
http://www.clemson.edu/cafls/departments/fnps/undergraduate/packaging_science_bs_degree/emphasis_areas.doc
http://www.erh.noaa.gov/lwx/em/Monday_EM_Briefing_current.docx
http://hr.colorado.edu/hrits/docs/Documents/SharePoint%202010%20Training.docx
http://www.k12lessonplans.com/uploads/downloads/1114.doc
https://www.hss.edu/files/Muscle-Rupture-Involving-Gastrocnemius-Soleus-Muscles-Hematoma.doc
http://ethics.calbar.ca.gov/Portals/9/documents/Civility/Civility-and-Ethics.doc
http://leadfree.ipc.org/files/RoHSLessons0707.doc
http://www.healthychildcare.org/Building%20Bridges%20resources/PowerPoints/PRESENTATION_Pediatricians.docx
http://www.joms.org/article/S0278-2391(13)00295-4/doc
http://ingilizceslayt.com/slides/WILL%20%E2%80%93%20BE%20GOING%20TO.doc
http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/ttoole/Kansas%20City%20DfCS%20presentation.doc
http://www.alexa.com/
http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1322481.files/S005%20Reliability%20checks%20v2.doc
http://rustin.pbworks.com/f/The+Hero%E2%80%99s+Journey+%232.docx
http://eshare.stust.edu.tw/EshareFile/2013_5/2013_5_b4c4905a.docx
http://sbs.wsu.edu/biol352/ControlofGeneExpression.doc
http://www.ohio.edu/plantbio/staff/showalte/PBIO%20450%20&%20550/Emch.docx
http://www.mcet.org/mining/environment/Toolkit/Training%20Presentations/Developing%20SWPPP%20Presentation/Dev_SWPPP%20Presentation.doc
http://www.uic.edu/classes/phyb/phyb402dbh/Hypothalamus%20and%20Pituitary.doc
http://www.cancer.org/acs/groups/content/@research/documents/document/acspc-041647.docx
http://adem.arkansas.gov/adem/Documents/Final_AR_FPC_Slide_Show_%20V2_4_17_11.ppsx
http://web.mit.edu/14.160/www/mit-lecture%2011%20(limited%20rationality&strategic%20interaction)2.doc
http://ieee-icsc.org/icsc2013/ICSC2013_Luciano_Tutorial.docx
https://www.niams.nih.gov///News_and_Events/Meetings_and_Events/Reports/2006/RR14_FDA_Schrager.doc
http://static.schoolrack.com/files/13968/580817/Light_-_electromagnetic_Spectrum%2C_reflection%2C_refraction_2013.docx
http://www1.eere.energy.gov/hydrogenandfuelcells/docs/doe_presentation.doc
http://mrsdooley.webs.com/AP%20Lang%20&%20Comp/Figures%20of%20Speech.docx
http://research.che.tamu.edu/groups/Seminario/CHEN320_Fall_2013_files/num-g05-massflow.docx
http://planningservices.partners.extranet.microsoft.com/en/SDPS/SAPSDocuments/SDPS%202014%20SharePoint%20Office%20Web%20Apps.docx
http://www.biogazrhonealpes.org/doc/methanisation_agricole/techniques/WP4_1_biochimie_et_suivi_digesteur.doc
http://www.cdc.gov/tb/education/skillscourse/Day1/Interview%20Question%20Types/Day%201-%20Interview%20Question%20Types_Final.docx
http://www.waseantourism.com/ft/Toolbox%20Development%20II:%2098%20toolboxes%20for%20Front%20Office,%20F&%20B%20Services%20and%20Food%20Production/Submission%20to%20ASEC/3rd%20submission%20of%2025%20draft%20TBs_200413/Apply%20std%20safety%20procedures%20for%20handling%20foodstuff/doc_Apply%20safety%20proc%20handling%20food_Final.docx
http://www.usda.gov/egov/egov_redesign/intranet/usability/Readiness_Assessment_v7.doc
http://www.almaden.ibm.com/institute/resources/2008/presentations/Brenda.doc
http://biologyonline.us/Online%20A&P/AP%202/Northland/AP2PowerPoint/A&P%202%20Urinary%20System%202005.doc
http://www.topdownbook.com/chapters/Chapter09.doc
http://www.castonline.ilstu.edu/smith/164/grp_3_go2.docx
http://mapit.gov.in/doc_of_traning/MP%20Online%20-%20AeGM%20Training.doc
http://www.ap.gatech.edu/Burkholder/4600/slides/21-CompensatoryHypertrophy.doc
http://www.agrisk.umn.edu/conference/uploads/BOelke0257_03.doc
http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ARE/sabeer/Site_Analysis_Example.doc
http://seed.ucsd.edu/Onlinecrs/rsrc/Onlinecrs/AnupDoshiLesson/Mindreader2.doc
http://ccba.jsu.edu/ccba/faculty/facultyFiles/jzanzig_Acc%20512%20-%20Chapter%207.doc
http://kehsscience.org/Intro%20to%20Ecology.docx
http://www.la-ptac.org/events/downloadFile.jsp?path=/siteSpecific/1118/Files/Articles/&file=Small_Business_Summit.doc
http://ace.arkansas.gov/cte/Documents/Microsoft%20IT%20Academy/Getting%20Started%20Virtual%20training%202012.docx
http://crninet.com/2013/2b.%20Kiewiet-Presentation.docx
http://portal.unesco.org/geography/es/files/11957/1259950117505_Seamus_Hegarty.doc/05%2BSeamus%2BHegarty.doc
http://edcmail.mui.ac.ir/images/stories/powerpoint/azar91/91.9.9/Dr.norozi,Liver%20-%20Incidentalomas2.docx
http://www.eurostemcell.org/files/CSI_PowerPoint_slides_FINAL_17July2012.doc
http://classes.engr.oregonstate.edu/mime/winter2010/ie337-001/Lectures/IE%20337%20W10%20Lecture%206.machining.operations&machinability.doc
http://maine.gov/msl/libs/tech/diglit/present2013.docx
http://campuses.fortbendisd.com/campuses/documents/Teacher/2009/teacher_20090209_1031_2.doc
http://bama.ua.edu/~st497/doc/consensusbaseddecision.doc
http://www.aiha.org/get-involved/outreach/Documents/IAQIntroTR.doc
http://chotenmien.vn/
http://www.ise.ncsu.edu/wysk/courses/ISE316/ISE316-Course-presentation/Chapter%2020.docx
http://www.belgianbraincouncil.be/files/2010.09.16_EXPECTATIONS_AND_RIGHTS_OF_PATIENTS_SUFFERING_FROM_A_BRAIN_DISORDER.doc
http://imp.uwe.ac.uk/imp_public/displayentry.asp?URN=6109&pid=16
http://classes.mst.edu/edtech/TLT2012/presentations/TLT-2012-mhays-BbCollaborate-01.docx
http://asja-eg.com/admin/cmes/files/Pediatric%20equipmentfinal.docx
http://www.outreach.mcb.harvard.edu/teachers/Summer05/ElizabethMick/TheNervousSystem.doc
http://nttc.columbiabasin.edu/automotive/doc_BTC-auto/fluidcouplers.doc
http://www.karentimberlake.com/doc%20Energy/Heating%20Curves.doc
http://sde.ok.gov/sde/sites/ok.gov.sde/files/documents/files/Document%20%2323--%20Don't%20PrintCharter%20School%20REVISED%203-3-2015.docx
http://geology.uprm.edu/Classes/GEOL3055/cmor.doc
http://www.techcoachcorner2.org/Curriculum%20Links/Writing/hook.doc
http://www.esiee.fr/%7Epoulichp/Magnetique/CoursCapteurMag+ActionMag.doc
http://www.doa.la.gov/orm/doc/supervisory_responsibility.doc
http://sharepoint.mvla.net/teachers/SophiaC/Backup/Tanks.doc
http://joshua-cox.webs.com/How%20to%20Play%20Checkers.doc
http://www.nyswysa.org/downloads/markedwards.doc
http://www.health.nsw.gov.au/mhdao/workforcedev/Documents/forum-pres/neami-nat-abor-link-prog.docx
http://aps.anl.gov/epics/irmis/2005-03/A07-Keitel-TRIUMF.doc
http://instructional1.calstatela.edu/prosent/CIS%20581/chapter8.docx
http://cominkamotors.com/bienvenidos.doc
http://www.sjsu.edu/people/steven.lee/courses/c4/s1/Trace_lecture_1.doc
http://englishexchange.pbworks.com/f/Advanced+Reading+and+Discussion.doc
http://www.techdata.com/(S(rnlsv045xrvvep55z05wfa45))/business/emc/files/VNXecollateral/VNXe_DD160%20Bundle%20-%20Overview%20(customer%20presentation).doc
http://www.eastportmpa.com/Powerpoint%20Presentations/Eastport%20MPA%20Version%201.doc
http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/med/study/ugr/mbchb/societies/slime/products/handouts/cushings_addisons_and_acromegaly_ed.docx
http://www.poac-nova.org/news_uploads/3545/process_tips_writing_goals_2012_ieps.doc
https://vle.york.ac.uk/bbcswebdav/xid-289133_4
https://www.vdh.virginia.gov/LHD/ThomasJefferson/documents/2011/doc/drkavanaughOBmortalitypresentation.docx
http://usian.org/table.php?long-term-psychosis-of-metoprolol-succinate.docx
http://jaymetracy.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/57894206/Chapter%201.1%20What%20is%20Fashion.docx
http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/resourcecenter/teams/civilrights/cr_ppp8.doc
http://www.nihpromis.org/Documents/Standards%20Slides_5-22-12-508compliant.docx
http://www.rkent.myweb.cs.uwindsor.ca/cs367/Chapter_4_V6.0.docx
http://www.shrm.org/TemplatesTools/Samples/PowerPoints/Documents/09-doc-Employee%20Recognition_FINAL.docx
http://static.schoolrack.com/files/223037/707743/Globe_Theatre.doc
http://lwthspn.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/87919174/A%26P%20Unit%204%20Skeletal%20student%20Ch8.docx
http://www.dgelman.com/powerpoints/geometry/spitz/10.6%20Equations%20of%20Circles.doc
http://www.falmouthschools.org/File/Population_Ecology_Chapter_52.doc
http://medicine.missouri.edu/financial/uploads/BYOB-2012.docx
http://www.ltisdschools.org/cms/lib09/TX21000349/Centricity/Domain/1328/8%20adverbs.doc
http://ncheney.com/official.php?doxycycline-dosage-for-malaria-prophylaxis.docx
http://moodle.penyrheol-comp.swansea.sch.uk/pluginfile.php/21074/mod_label/intro/Tourism.docx
http://blog.stikom.edu/anjik/files/2012/08/PT5_0_Overview_14Jul08.docx
http://tulane.edu/som/departments/medicine/gastroenterology/resident-portal/upload/HepCC022415.docx
ttp://www.sciencedirect.gr/
http://me.uprm.edu/sundaram/inme%204007/INME4007-6.doc
http://cbesio.cox.smu.edu/mktg3344/course%20files/class_notes/Market%20Segmentation.doc
http://teachers.srsd.net/mstrada/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Parallel-and-Perpendicular-Lines2.docx
https://www.icsi.edu/docs/40nc/4TechSesonGopalkrishna.pps
http://www.pedstudent.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/pals_11.doc
http://webscripts.esd101.net/safety/PowerPoint%20Training/R_01.doc
http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/MS/DeSotoCounty/HernandoHigh/Uploads/Presentations/Chapter%2012%20Industrial%20Rev.%20section%201.docx
http://www.mocs.gov.np/uploads/Role%20of%20Customs%20in.docx
http://www.wainwright.army.mil/nwtc/Classes/Slides/Planning%20Considerations%20for%20Oversnow%20Movement.doc
http://www.hydrologicalusa.com/images/uploads/Hydrological_Services_America.docx
http://web.iitd.ac.in/~ravi1/++++LEVI/doc/ch01_final.doc
http://www.seminarscolonrectalsurgery.com/article/S1043-1489(05)00066-7/doc
http://www.esc14.net/users/0076/docs/spp7/Ind%20%207%20Request%20TEASE%20Access%202012-13.docx
http://www.andrews.edu/shp/speech/resources/anatomyandphysiology/physiologyofarticulation2.docx
http://www.clubs.psu.edu/up/actsci/resume%20info%204-7-14.docx
http://www.dgelman.com/powerpoints/algebra/alg2/spitz/1.3%20Solving%20Linear%20Equations.doc
http://www.multistatepartnership.org/docs/Wednesday/18-Deacon-Advantages-of-Regional-Partnerships.docx
https://faculty.elgin.edu/jputz/CIS%20230%20Chapter%201%2002.docx
http://www.cfoa.org.uk/download/12887
http://www.jvascsurg.org/article/S0741-5214(11)00608-2/doc
http://feti.lsu.edu/municipal/NFA/TRADE/materials/TRADE%20CD%201/POWER%20POINT%20PROGRAMS/Acountability.doc
https://www.roadsafetyworkshop.com/doc/day2/6.%20Samir%20Raval-SCDP%20(12.8.16)%20(1).docx%20%2062%20slides.docx
http://www.uprb.edu/profesor/mvelez/cursos/ccom3033/docsgaddis/C05.doc
http://www.centralcancernetwork.org.nz/file/fileid/47896
http://medicine.missouri.edu/childhealth/uploads/congheartdisease.docx
http://rpids.csc.tntech.edu/_resources/Introduction/2140883132/2140883132.doc
http://faculty.uoh.edu.sa/b.hijah/documents/Chronic%20renal%20failure.doc
http://www.calvin.edu/admin/physicalplant/departments/ehs/policies/biosafety/Process%20Flow%20Chart%20for%20IBC.docx
http://instructional1.calstatela.edu/prosent/CIS%20581/chapter11.docx
http://tandtmidwives.com/source/resources/FUTURE_STRATEGIES_MIDWIFERY.ppsx
http://advantagegolfcars.com/bathroom.php?metronidazole-dose-of-acne-treatment.docx
http://www.bauer.uh.edu/pgalvani/files/MARK6361/Kotler14e_12.1_idoc.doc
http://kvsangathanectlt.com/topic_sys/Role%20of%20the%20%20goernment%20in%20health.doc
http://www.fgse.nova.edu/itde/faculty/simonson/doc/de_www.doc
http://www.scgcorp.com/OLD/MW/2008/7_Cantor%20status%20for%20Mgr%20Mtg%202008-11-06%20FINAL.doc
http://www.ars.usda.gov/SP2UserFiles/Place/19320000/Turner-Small%20Ruminant%20Steering%20Committee%20Meeting%20April%202006.doc
http://careers.michelin-us.com/reltech/reliability-docs/IMT/06-Lubricants.ppsx
https://schoolhistory.co.uk/year8links/natives/bighorn.doc
http://reporting.msue.msu.edu/miprs/online/extensionprogramevaluation.doc
http://linuxyw.com/width.php?dog-colitis-prednisone.docx
http://agriscience.msu.edu/2000/2010-2020/2023/2023seedanatomy.doc
http://kcooperict.wikispaces.com/file/view/Rudolf+Steiner.doc
http://www.vghks.gov.tw/cs/docfiles/OVERVI~1.doc
http://www.psycholosphere.com/Vessels%20on%20Learning%20&%20Memory.doc
http://www.cias.wisc.edu/curriculum/modII/secc/TCB_SoilQual_distrib.doc
http://nttc.columbiabasin.edu/automotive/WWCC/gears_ch_29.doc
http://cattlespring.org/sadness.php?over-weight-diet-pill.docx
http://think.stedwards.edu/campusrecreation/sites/think.stedwards.edu.campusrecreation/files/Club%20Sport%20Officer%20Meeting%20Fall%202015.docx
http://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/kruse/it110/CH02_NET+.doc
https://www.cpcc.edu/learning/campus-updates/stem-2016.doc
http://headandnecksurgery.ucla.edu/workfiles/Academics/Lectures/4-25-12_Gopen_Mastoid_Surgery_review.doc
http://static.schoolrack.com/files/19286/507009/Macronutrients.doc
http://iris.nyit.edu/~facevedo/ClinicalYearPresentations/OTITIS%20MEDIA.doc
http://parasitology.xjtu.edu.cn/powerpoint/Eng/T.g.doc
http://elearn.azpost.gov/FileContent/filesupload/AZDPS/AZDPS_2013_GasMaskFitTest/FRM40%20Gas%20Mask%20Training%20and%20Inspection%20Elearn%203_Reduced%20Version.ppsx
http://www.mysbdteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Brook-Kirwin-How-to-Bring-Business-in-the-Club.doc
http://www.fmdrl.org/index.cfm?event=c.getAttachment&riid=3140
https://library.e.abb.com/public/ef11d44d832d5e9ac125793c00343ce2/20111102%20PS%20Consulting%20Presentation.doc
http://www.ars.usda.gov/GARA/presentations/GARA%20Presentation%20South%20Africa,%20October%202014.docx
http://alhefzi.com/G34/Family/Seminars/Obesity%20&%20Dyslipidemia.docx
http://www.eucosh.org.cn/Documents/Activity%20outputs/1.5.2%20Non%20coal%20screening/The%20Hidden%20Hazards%20in%20Non-Coal%20Mining_Nick_rev.docx
http://www.hccfl.edu/media/518678/basic%20sentence%20patterns%20&%20punctuation.docx
http://www.gautehallansteiwer.com/term-papers-help.docx
http://www.aerbvi.org/2012international/documents/Flener-ResponsetoInterventionandIpad2Handout1_000.docx
http://csrri.iit.edu/~howard/biochem/lecdoc/sug3+lip1f10_401.doc
http://mbbsclub.com/download/3/Microbiology/Corynebacterium%20&%20Listeria.docx
http://www.henley.ac.uk/web/FILES/management/Alain_Verbeke.doc
http://www.psclg.org.sa/web/doc/Balance-Score-Card/BSC-Presentation.pps
http://www.ecu.edu/cs-cas/anth/nuevosouth/upload/ushispanicmarketoverview-finalcv5-5-09-090505155110-phpapp02.doc
http://healthcare.utah.edu/miners_hospital/outreach/Work-relatedAsthmaPowerPoint.doc
http://www.waynecc.edu/sherryg/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/EDU-251-Piaget-Theory.docx
http://www.castonline.ilstu.edu/henninger/Powerpoints/341/Percentile%20Rank,%20Percentile,%20Correlation.docx
http://www.californiaeducatorsnetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/California-Health-Science-Capacity-Building-Project-2010.doc
http://ww2.nmh.org/oweb/MagnetDoc/04_ep_exemplary_professional_practice/ep30-c_-_safety_representatives_meeting__presentation.doc
http://dhmh.maryland.gov/mbpme/documents/lecture09.doc
http://www.unh.edu/writing/cwc/presentations/media/effectivepresentations.doc
http://homepages.umflint.edu/~christsw/Classes/5%20Spring%202013/PTP%20641%20Med.Surgery/6.17.13%20General%20Medical%20Conditions%20and%20Surgeries%20Med%20Surg%20II.docx
http://www.safmls.org/2010/2010%20Presentations/W%201/The%20Beta-Lactamase%20Family.doc
http://www.fldoe.org/core/fileparse.php/7531/urlt/decision-making-process.doc
http://www.lhsc.on.ca/lab/qmanage/present/qms.doc
http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~rhabash/ELG4139L1PE.doc
http://www.agriscience.msu.edu/2000/2040/2041/2041.doc
http://instructional1.calstatela.edu/hye2/HNRS330/Chapter%20One/HNRS330_Chapter%20One.docx
http://kheseminar.com/doc/01DB74D1-2818-32BA-39B4-1AE702B5CEEF/Backup/a.doc
http://www.solonschools.org/accounts/NBarnes/23201092816_GravityandFreeFall.doc
http://static.schoolrack.com/files/45730/142314/Magnetic_Effects_of_Electric_Currents.doc
http://cancer.dartmouth.edu/lung_thoracic/documents/Nalepinski_CTOP_Retreat_COG_Update.docx
http://www.phscof.org/docs/PresentationsFinal/Tuesday/Pharmacy/SchupbachCOA_2011_DiabetesManagementGuidelinesUpdateSchupbach.docx
http://www.mexico.com.mx/
http://www.teachmebusiness.co.uk/resources/Factors_affecting_promotion.doc
http://www.unisa.edu.au/Documents/EASS/HRI/CPCM/faulks-best-interests.doc
http://delthabot.altervista.org/Lezioni/IV%20Anno/I%20Semestre/Gastroenterologia/20%20LEZIONE%20IPERTENSIONE%20PORTALE.doc
http://www.archbalt.org/youth-young-adult/upload/New-Evangelization.doc
http://www.canadianjournalofdiabetes.com/article/S1499-2671(10)44010-1/doc
http://pdic.tamu.edu/farmpolicy/josling.doc
http://www.waseantourism.com/ft/Approved%20Toolboxes%20&%20Competency%20standards/Prepare%20tenders%20for%20catering%20contracts/doc_Prepare_tenders_for_catering_contracts_FN_030214.docx
http://www.studentaffairs.colostate.edu/Data/Sites/1/programreviews2015/lsc-dining-services-program-review---dsa-directors---october-7-2015.docx
http://www2.dsu.nodak.edu/users/rbutz/International%20Business/PowerPoint/F09/Honda_S1_F09.docx
http://www.imbanaco.com/webfm_send/1043
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gets the result you show in your example.

```
grep '^[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/$' findmydomain.txt >new
```

These are not properly "domain names", they are URLs possibly with one or more subdomains.  For example, in `www.google.com`, the domain name is `google.com` and `www` is just an individual node name.  In the general case, resolving the TLD out of a hostname is a much more complex problem which requires knowledge of each individual TLD.

The final slash is optional, strictly speaking; @terdon's answer uses a more complex regex which solves this.  As a quick and dirty fix, you could add a `*` after the final slash here (which would however then also match `http://example.com///` with an arbitrary amount of redundant trailing slashes).  The regex looks for lines with exactly three slashes in them, with optional non-slash characters before and between them.

Comment: Thank you, Sorry, I forgot to ask earlier. I want to remove these domains from findmydomain.txt after extracted to a new file. how can I add this to this command ?

Comment: Use `grep -v` and the output will have those lines excluded.  These are very basic questions; have you tried googling?

Comment: can also use `grep -E '^([^/]*/){3}$'` which makes it easier to change numbers...

Comment: ok figured out with grep -v  thanks
grep -v -f new findmydomain.txt > filename235; mv -f filename235 findmydomain.txt

Answer (score 6):

A simple approach would be to just search for all lines that start with `http://` or `https://`, and have either no other `/` or only one, at the end. Using `grep` with extended regular expressions. for example:

```
$ grep -E 'http.?://[^/]+/?$' file
http://www.drexel.edu/
http://trianglewordpress.com/
http://www.nasa.gov/
http://www.alexa.com/
http://chotenmien.vn/
http://www.mexico.com.mx/
```

Comment: yes this command is also work perfectly thank you

Comment: `https?` would be a little more precise...

Comment: @heemayl future proof. Maybe next year we'll also have `httpy://`. OK, not very likely, but why not make it more flexible?

Answer (score 4):

One-pass `sed` solution:

```
sed -n '\_[^:/]/._!{p;d};w out.txt' findmydomain.txt
```

The URLs without a path (like `http://xxx.com/` or `https://yyy.org`, with or without trailing slash) get written to the file `out.txt`, while the others are printed and can be redirected to another file (or you use the `-i` option to edit in place, if your `sed` supports it).

The pattern `[^:/].` matches any occurence of a slash that is not following another slash or a colon (so it's not from `http://`) and preceeds another char.

I did use `\_..._` instead of `/.../` to select the line, so I don't need to escape the slahes in the pattern (thanks to @tripleee for reminding me to explain that!).

Comment: Maybe also mention that `\_` marks the underscore as the match separator so that you can use a literal slash in the regex without needing to escape it.

Comment: You are right, I should add that to the explanation. Updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If input file contains a list of URL, it is easier to say what we want to skip .

With grep: `grep -v`

```
grep -v  '//.*/.' file.txt
```

With awk: ignore if we have a *file* or *dir* = print if empty $4)

```
awk -F/ '!$4'     file.txt
```

Answer (score -3):

What about an `awk` solution?

`cat domain.txt |awk -F"/" '{print $1 $2"//" $3"/"}'`:

```
http://www.drexel.edu/
http://trianglewordpress.com/
http://www.nasa.gov/
http://www.mexico.com.mx/
```

The domain.txt is the input file.

Comment: The [`cat` is useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) and the single quotes around `$1` break the script.

Comment: Update the answer

Comment: The task is not to strip everything after the server name, but to select only the URLs without a file path.